# Getting error 401 while fetching data with axios in Laravel

Tags: laravel, vue.js, http, axios

I am trying to fetch some **reports** with axios in Laravel. I tested it in Postman and everything is fine.
But here I got error 401.
Here is my code:

#Reports.vue file

```
<template>
    <div>
        <h1>All reports: </h1>
        <div v-for="report in reports" v-bind:key="report.id">
            <p>{{ report.description }}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name: "Reports",
        data ()  {
            return  {
                reports : [],
            }
        },
        mounted() {
            this.fetchReports();
        },
        methods : {
            async fetchReports() {
                const {data} = await axios.get('/api/report');
                this.reports = data.data;
            },
        }
    }
</script>
```

#ReportController@index

```
public function index()
{
    $reports = Report::all();

    return ReportResource::collection($reports);
}
```

#api.php

```php
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth:api'], function () {    
  Route::apiResource('/report', 'API\ReportController');
});
```

Thanks in advance. If You need more informations, I will post them.

Answer (score 0):

Laravels `auth:api` middleware require you to pass Bearer token or `?api_token=` url param with your request

[Source](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/api-authentication#protecting-routes)

And I don't see you passing token with your axios request

Comment: I am passing the token correctly. I tested it via Postman... My logic for passing it is in AuthController... I am not sure what mistake I made here... If I find out today, I will post what mistake was about. Thanks anyway!